# JFX8 Eclipse4.4 AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(Button, 10.0); error

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-8

have some errors with JFX8... Want to implement some 3D-objects via Modelimporter.
Why cant I set the Anchorpanes, im getting

"The method setLeftAnchor(Node, Double) in the type AnchorPane is not applicable for the arguments (Button, double)"

but in every example they are using Buttons or List which are addet to the anchors...

```
import com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.ImportException;
import com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.tds.TdsModelImporter;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Camera;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFx1 extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}


public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(); 

    Button btnUp = new Button("blubb");

    final Camera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();  

    //
    // importing 3ds Modell
    // 
    TdsModelImporter myModel = new TdsModelImporter();
        try {
            String path =                        "C:/Users/Corvin/Downloads/DUC916_L.3DS/DUC916_L.3DS";
            myModel.read(path);
        }
        catch (ImportException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error importing 3ds model: "+e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

    //
    // adding Modell
    //
    final Node[] myMesh = myModel.getImport();
    myModel.close();
    final Group model3D = new Group(myMesh);

    //
    // setting Anchorpane and scene and start
    //
    root.setLeftAnchor(btnUp, 10d);
    root.getChildren().add(model3D);
    root.getChildren().add(btnUp);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, true);
    scene.setCamera(camera);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();   
}
```

}

Comment: It looks ok - maybe due to eclipse - does it compile with javac?

Comment: looks like the autoboxing of double => Double does not work! What compiler source/class level have you set? If you use JDK8 Eclipse currently does not detect that appropriately and sets it to 1.4!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but with Eclipse Kepler 4.3.1 and JRE8 it works. With Eclipse SDK 4.4M not and there are some other errors too ...